# Mac address for DM9000a on Nios ii

Tags: mac-address, nios

I have an assignment to communicate between computer and DE2 board by using Nios ii and module DM9000A.

I found in file DM9000A.c

```
  /* store MAC address into NIC */
  for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
  iow(16 + i, ether_addr[i]);
```

and in file DM9000A.h

```
unsigned char ether_addr[6]={ 0x01, 0x60, 0x6E, 0x11, 0x02, 0x0F  };
```

And project Simple Socket for DE2 use this Mac address for source address in UDP packet.

So, is that the Mac address of network card?

Comment: Solution: Board DE2 use Davicom Ethernet chip and we can change the last 3 bye of Mac address before initial DM9000 module.